# position background image with \SetBgAnchor

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I want to print an A4 page on B4 stock, with crop marks and bleeding square grid. I use `memoir` for crop marks, and `background` with TikZ for the grid. I would like the `(0,0)` in TikZ be placed at the bottom left corner: ideally of the cropped area (as I don't know how to do that, the example has it at the corner of the stock page).

I am having troubles positioning the grid relative to the where I need using the `\SetBgAnchor` command. The `background` documentation says that a typical use would be `\SetBgAnchor{north east}`, but that gives me

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/north east' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

The code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,b4paper,showtrims]{memoir}
% a4 paper centerd on b4
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*} 
\settrims{28mm}{20mm}
\trimLmarks

\usepackage{background}

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{blue!30}
% corner left bottom, span the grid over the page
% I will need about 3mm of bleed, but that's easy once bg is positioned
\SetBgContents{\tikz{\draw[step=5mm] (28mm,20mm) grid (225mm,315mm);}}
\SetBgPosition{current page.south west}
\SetBgAnchor{}  % should be {south west}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    Some text
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled code above]

Questions are therefore:

1. How to fix my code so that the grid is positions properly?
2. Is there a way to have to TikZ coordinates start at the bottom left corner of the cropped page rather than stock page?

Comment: Yes; it's a bug in `background`; I will correct it as soon as I can; I will give you a workarond shortly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a bug in the `background` package (thanks for detecting it). As a workaround while I upload a new version of the package, you can pass all your options directly to `\bg@material`, as the following example shows (I wasn't sure about the desired grid position):

```
\documentclass[10pt,b4paper,showtrims]{memoir}
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\settrims{28mm}{20mm}
\trimLmarks

\usepackage{background}

\makeatletter
\def\bg@material{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [rotate=0,scale=1,opacity=0.6,color=blue!30,xshift=28mm,yshift=20mm]
at (current page.south west)  [anchor=south west]{\tikz{\draw[step=5mm] (28mm,20mm) grid (225mm,315mm);}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For question 2, is there no way? I can live without that, but it would be convenient.

Comment: @eudoxos: if I understand your question correctly, you can use `\pgfsys@transformshift{x displacement}{y displacement}` inside the `tikzpicture` environment: for example, `\makeatletter
\pgfsys@transformshift{30pt}{-100pt}
\makeatother`

Comment: I was thinking that `background`/TikZ perhaps pre-defines a rectangle for the "text area" of the page I could refer to (`text area.south west`). It probably does not, that is fine as well. Thanks.