# TikZ current page.north west shifted ~4pts?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm trying to draw a background grid on a page, but `current page.north west` is shifted down and to the right ~4pt.  Anyone know how I can get the *exact* north west corner of the page?

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[papersize={2.5in,0.5in},margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
  \node at (current page.north west) [anchor=north west]{%
    \tikz{\draw[step=0.25in,color=red,thick] (0,0)
      grid (\paperwidth,\paperheight);}%
  };%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
In Ti\emph{k}Z, \texttt{current page.north west} is shifted $\sim$4pt
right and down%
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should try something like `\draw[red,thick] (current page.north west) grid[step=0.25in] (current page.south east);`

Comment: @remjg:  That works if I do south east to north west and use the `background` package.  Thanks for the hint!

Comment: The *exact* north west corner is at `(current page.north west)`. Why are you nesting TikZ pictures in the first place (see remjg’s comment)?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel:  I'm nesting a TikZ picture inside a node because (1) I don't know what I'm doing :) and (2) that's what the author of the `background` package did in [his answer to a related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47886/6185).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are putting the grid inside a `node` and nodes have `inner sep`aration. Make `inner sep` zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[papersize={2.5in,0.5in},margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
  \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north west) [anchor=north west]{%
    \tikz{\draw[step=0.25in,color=red,thick] (0,0)
      grid (\paperwidth,\paperheight);}%
  };%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
In Ti\emph{k}Z, \texttt{current page.north west} is shifted $\sim$4pt
right and down%
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your goal is to add a grid to the page, you may use `pagegrid` package. Just add `\usepackage{pagegrid}` in the preamble to get the grid.

**Response to comment**

Putting `inner sep=-0.4pt,` will give

[image]

This works well for the default line width. However, it is better to use `inner sep = -\pgflinewidth` instead of `inner sep=-0.4pt`. It may be noted that the default value of  `\pgflinewidth` is `0.4pt`. (Thanks to **Jake** for pointing out)

Comment: Thanks!  I would have expected the middle of the grid lines to line up with the page corner (so that all around the edge of the page you'd see a 1/2 thickness red line), but I can work with this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.  I assume that the thickness of the line is 0.8pt?  I'm guessing that the center of the grid lines aren't aligned with the corner of the page without that offset because of `anchor=north west` (I'm guessing that puts the anchor at the north west corner of the bounding box, which would include the entire thickness of the lines).

Comment: @RichardHansen: Is there a reason that you use a node for the grid instead of `\draw ($(current page.north west)+(-\pgflinewidth/2,\pgflinewidth/2)$) grid …`

Comment: @Tobi:  No reason, other than that's what the author of the `background` package did in [his answer to a related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47886/6185).  I'm still trying to understand TikZ (its syntax rules are not straightforward), so I was copying what I saw elsewhere.  A comment by remjg led me to a simpler way to do what I want, but I'm still glad I learned what went wrong with the awkward approach used in my question.

Comment: @RichardHansen: The tutorials in the manual (`pgfmanual.pdf`) are a good start to learn TikZ. A `node` can be used to add text to a picture other picture elements (such as grids) don’t require a `node`. The `node`s are much more powerful but too powerful for this comment ;-)