# Locating north west corner of text area

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I would like to locate the exact position of the north west corner of the text area. Using `\layout` (see image in *Notes* section), it seems that the required offset from `current page.north west` is

```
xshift=1.0in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin,
yshift=-1.0in-\voffset-\headsep,
```

### Using `showframe` package: (as in MWE)

The image below is the north west corner of the text area at 6400% zoom where I have placed a gray `+` and a filled in circle.  This visually looks like it is pretty close to the correct location. However, to get to this position required an additional tweak of

```
(-0.35pt,2.35pt)%% Required shift to obtain image below (see MWE)
```

from the above parameters.

The somewhat related questions listed in the *References* section mention an issue with `inner sep` and `\parindent`, both of which have been accounted for. (They are actually not needed here, but added them anyway).

Why is this additional tweak required?

[image]

### Using showframe *option* to `geometry` package:

IF instead of using the `showframe` package, I instead use

```
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
```

The tweak required is slightly different:

```
(-0.1pt,1.8pt)
```

which yields:

[image]

### References:

- [TikZ: Anchor current page north west isn't where expected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339970/4301).
- [TikZ current page.north west shifted ~4pts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129109/4301).

### Notes:

- Using `\layout`, we obtain the following picture from which I obtained the parameters to compute the exact location of the north west of the text area.

  [image]

  [image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcommand*{\ShowNorthWestOfTextArea}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \coordinate (X) at ([
            xshift=1.0in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin-0.35pt,
            yshift=-1.0in-\voffset-\headsep+2.35pt,
        ]current page.north west);

    \draw [draw=red, fill=yellow, text=gray] (X) circle (1pt)
        node [inner sep=0pt] {+};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%


\begin{document}%\layout% <-- uncomment to obtain the layout parameters
\noindent\ShowNorthWestOfTextArea%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does [tikzpagenodes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) help? Specifically, once it is loaded you can use `(current page text area.north west)`.

Comment: Actually, loading `tikzpagenodes` and doing `\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
\draw [draw=red, fill=yellow, text=gray] (current page text area.north west) circle (1pt)
        node [inner sep=0pt] {+};}` seems to indicate that the frame is around the text area, meaning that the line is outside and your mark is already a tiny bit outside the text area, precisely by the additional shift.

Comment: @Andrew: Yep, `tikzpagenodes` seems to do the correct position without any tweaks, so that is definitely the solution to use instead of computing it directly. I'd still be interested in what is going on though.  Seems to imply some issue with either `showframe` package (and `showframe` option to `geometry`) or a deficiency with the `layout` package.

Comment: @PeterGrill I really think it is the line width. The frame is drawn in such a way that the line is completely outside the text area, but the inner boundary of the frame is the outer boundary of the text area. You place your mark in the middle of the line.

Comment: @marmot: The `1.8pt` tweak is rather large to just be an issue with the line width (which I think is probably on the order of 0.4pt).

Comment: I think the line is a bit thicker than the usual line width of `0.4pt`, and guess it is `0.7pt`, which explains the additional `xshift`. As for the `yshift`, I do not understand what's going on.

Comment: @marmot: Agreed. BTW, not sure if you noticed but I updated the question: seems as if you use the `showframe` option to the `geometry` package, the line width is a more reasonable.

Comment: @Andrew: Do you want to post an answer showing how to use `tikzpagenodes` as that is the correct way to reference the point I was trying to locate. I accepted Circumscribe's answer as that explained what was gong on.

Comment: @PeterGrill Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Position of the text area relative to the page corner

The top of the `\layout` image generally looks like the image below, but in your case the dashed line appears to coincide with the bottom of the header because ④ (`\topmargin` = -13pt) and ⑤ (`\headheight` = 12pt) nearly cancel out.

[image: distances]

You can read off that the horizontal/vertical distance between the top left corner of the text with respect to the top left corner of the page are

> horizontal distance = `1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin` or `1in+\hoffset+\evensidemargin`,
>   vertical distance = `1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep`

(*`\oddsidemargin` is for single-sided documents and odd pages of double-sided documents, and `\evensidemargin` for even pages of double-sided documents.*)

### Position of the text area relative to `current page.north west`

For TikZ, the coordinates of the top left corner of the text area are (w.r.t. `current page.north west`)

```
(1in+\oddsidemargin, -1in-2\voffset-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep)
```

for a single-sided document and odd pages of double-sided documents (and the same with `\evensidemargin` for even pages of a double-sided document).

> **Note:** I have no clue why you would need to add `-2\voffset` to the y coordinate, but it seems like a bug.
>   Perhaps a sign error was made somewhere in the code when correcting for `\voffset`?
>
> Usually `\hoffset` and `\voffset` are both equal to zero, however, so this won't matter.

Here is a version of your MWE with the right parameters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{geometry}

\newcommand*{\ShowNorthWestOfTextArea}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \coordinate (X) at ([
            xshift=1.0in+\oddsidemargin,
            yshift=-1.0in-2\voffset-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep,
        ]current page.north west);

    \draw [draw=red, fill=yellow, text=gray] (X) circle (1pt)
        node [inner sep=0pt] {+};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\noindent\ShowNorthWestOfTextArea%

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that `showframe` draws a border *around* the text area.

Comment: Any idea why `\layout` with `\usepackage{layout}` in your MWE does not produce the layout image you show?

Comment: The appearance of `\layout` depends on the lengths it is illustrating. The horizontal dashed line appears below the top of the header because the `geometry` package sets `topmargin` to a negative value. The word "should" was probably not appropriate in the first paragraph.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I guess the `\layout` package should check to see if `geometry` is loaded and adult the drawing appropriately -- Or at least check if the parameters are set such that it is difficult to draw a useful layout.

Answer (score 3):

The package [tikzpagenodes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) provides a useful set of [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) coordinates for:

- current page text area
- current page marginpar area
- current page header area
- current page footer area

So, if [tikzpagenodes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) is loaded then you can get the "north west corner of the text area" using
`(current page text area.north west)` from inside a `tikzpicture` environment. You will need to use `remember picture,overlay` for this to work.

Adapting the MWE from the question, we can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcommand*{\ShowNorthWestOfTextArea}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \coordinate (X) at (current page text area.north west);

  \draw [draw=red, fill=yellow, text=gray] (X) circle (1pt)
      node [inner sep=0pt] {+};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%


\begin{document}%\layout% <-- uncomment to obtain the layout parameters
  \ShowNorthWestOfTextArea%
\end{document}
```

With this code, the north west corner of the text area looks like:

[image]