# Tikz: position relative to body, not page

Tags: tikz-pgf, letters, remember

I'd like to position a picture on the top-left part of the body of a letter (but I'm interested more generally by a solution that works for any class), so that there are some margins between the image and the paper end.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\signature{Me}
\address{This is me\\ \\ I live somewhere \\ But you won't \\Find me}
% \fancypagestyle{empty}{\includegraphics[height=0.5in, keepaspectratio=true]{logo-lip6.png}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{To Whom It May Concern: }
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=north west] at (current page.north west){\includegraphics[width=4cm, keepaspectratio=true]{example-image-a}};

Here is my letter. I'd like to put the image on the top-left part of the body, not of the page (I'm not sure how ``body'' is defined in letter, but it would be great if the image starts at the same height as ``This is me'', and left aligned, like the ``To Whom It May Concern''.

\closing{Yours Faithfully,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use the `xshift` and `yshift` option like this `\node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=north west,xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]`. There is an example at page 261 of the [pgf manual](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: @AlainRemillard The problem is that I don't know what margin I have on the document, and I don't want to do dirty manual adjustements... (it's what I'm doing for now, but I would like a "proper" solution)

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/463069/162128) can help?

Comment: I suggest `tikzmark` library

Comment: Your question is unfortunately ambiguous. You write "so that there are some margins between the image and the paper end" and the title is "Tikz: position relative to body, not page". These statements contradict each other. Maybe you want to make the question unambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `tikzpagenodes` package and its `current page text area` node.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\signature{Me}
\address{This is me\\ \\ I live somewhere \\ But you won't \\Find me}
% \fancypagestyle{empty}{\includegraphics[height=0.5in, keepaspectratio=true]{logo-lip6.png}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{To Whom It May Concern: }
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
  \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=north west]
  at (current page text area.north west)
  {\includegraphics[width=4cm, keepaspectratio=true]{example-image-a}};
}

Here is my letter. I'd like to put the image on the top-left part of the
body, not of the page (I'm not sure how ``body'' is defined in letter,
but it would be great if the image starts at the same height as ``This
is me'', and left aligned, like the ``To Whom It May Concern''.

\closing{Yours Faithfully,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

> [image]