# How to cover the entire page area with grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, geometry

I'm missing something, but the grid in my example doesn't want to cover the entire page area. There are unwanted margins on the top.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, margin=0pt, includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[step=1.0,gray,thin] (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `geometry` in the first place. The whole point of `standalone` is that is adapts it self to the size of the contents. Thus adjust your `tikzpicture` to give it an actual size instead of trying to make it fit the document size as it is "undefined" in `standalone` (for a4paper: `\draw[step=1.0,gray,thin] (0,0) grid (210mm,297mm);`)

Comment: as daleif said, you don't need `geometry`. all you need is `\documentclass[tikz,a4paper,landscape]{standalone}`

Comment: What are you trying to do?? standalone adapts the page size to the content, but your content tries to adapt to the page size, I'm getting dizzy trying to imagine what should be the outcome here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok. I change the documentclass to article, and did not achieve entire page coverage and got one extra page left. I don't seem to understand how to customize the geometry package

Comment: I believe you have a problem of not being clear about what you want. Do you want a page that has a grid on its background?

Comment: If that is the case, you can use the `background` package https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/background/background.pdf. Also refer to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47875/position-background-image-with-setbganchor

Comment: If you want to draw arbitrary shapes on your pages as overlay, `tikz` does that. https://latexdraw.com/how-to-create-a-lined-paper-background-in-latex-using-tikz/#t-1609956819736

Comment: @anis I just need to fill the entire page with a grid, with any documentclass. But for some reason, even when I specify null marging in options of geometry package, they still appear. I then need to set the nodes on the grid, and if there are extra margins there, the picture will move, which I don’t need at all.

Comment: you're missing the `overlay,remember picture` options to the tikzpicture1`

Comment: @daleif `overlay,remember picture` Thanks, that's how it works!

Comment: you could use the pagegrid package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer add it as answer?

Answer (score 4):

Although the question isn't clear, you apparently are trying to draw a grid on the background of a page.

You can use either `tikz` package alone for a single page or combine it with `background` to get it in pages you want.

### Single page

```
\documentclass[a4paper,margin=0pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for the filling text
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[step=1.0,gray,thin] (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

### Background

```
\documentclass[A4paper,margin=0pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for the filling text

\usepackage{background}

\makeatletter
\def\bg@material{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[step=1.0,gray,thin] (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
            \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

the code was borrowed from [position background image with \SetBgAnchor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47875/position-background-image-with-setbganchor)

Also, possible duplicate.

Comment: Thank you, as I realized from the comments, I just forgot `overlay, remember picture` and geometry package nothing to do with here.

Comment: You can also use `\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{...}`. Frankly, the background package is obsolete, although is still works.